# Problema com ModelSerializer do Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialização, django-rest-framework

Tenho duas models que elas tem uma relação ManyToMany entre elas, elas são:

```
class Filiais(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_empresa = models.IntegerField()
    sigla = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)

class Clientes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    filiais = models.ManyToManyField(
        Filiais,
        verbose_name=("clientes"),
        through="ClientesFiliais",
    )

class ClientesFiliais(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filial = models.ForeignKey(Filiais, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    saldo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

E tenho esses **serializers**:

```
class FiliaisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Filiais
        fields = [
            "id",
            "id_garagem",
            "sigla",
        ]

class ClientesFiliaisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientesFiliais
        fields = "__all__"
        delth = 1

class ClientesResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filiais = ClientesFiliaisSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Clientes
        fields = (
            "id",
            "razao_social_motorista",
            "cnpj_cpf",
            "filiais",
        )
        delth = 1
```

Tenho essa rota GET:

```
def get(self, request: Request) -> Response:
    clientes = Clientes.objects.all()
    serializer = ClientesResponseSerializer(clientes, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Porém quando eu acesso essa rota é gerado o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `cliente` on serializer `ClientesFiliaisSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Filiais` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Filiais' object has no attribute 'cliente'.
```

Esse erro ocorre quando o *fields* do **ClientesFiliaisSerializer** tem o valor tanto de *filial* quanto de *cliente*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar um campo chamado "cliente" no ClientesBranchesSerializer, mas o campo não existe no modelo de Branches.

Verifique se você está referenciando os campos apropriados nos serializadores corretamente.

Proponho o seguinte código:

```
class FiliaisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Filiais
        fields = [
            "id",
            "id_empresa",
            "sigla",
        ]

class ClientesFiliaisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filial = FiliaisSerializer()  # adicionar este campo

    class Meta:
        model = ClientesFiliais
        fields = "__all__"
        delth = 1

class ClientesResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filiais = ClientesFiliaisSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Clientes
        fields = (
            "id",
            "razao_social",
            "cnpj",
            "filiais",
        )
        delth = 1
```